# MySQL Case always executes the same

Tags: mysql, case

What I want to do is to set DATE_REACT a value when the first condition is satisfied, and a different value when the first condition is not satisfied. The problem is that the first condition is executed always, even when it shouldn't. What I am doing wrong?

```
UPDATE BILLS
SET STATE = 2,
DATE_REACT =
CASE 
WHEN (DATE_EM <= CURTIME() <= ADDTIME(DATE_EM, '00:02:00')) 
THEN ADDTIME(CURTIME(), '00:13:00')
ELSE ADDTIME(DATE_REACT, '00:13:00')
END
WHERE STATE = 1;
```